# Spring Data Jpa difference between findBy... and findBy...Equals

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a Book entity with String name field. Is there any difference when using Spring Data JPA keywords between:

```
Optional<Book> findByName(String name);
```

and

```
Optional<Book> findByNameEquals(@NonNull String name);
```

to find a book with a particular name?

Comment: read https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-derived-queries chapter 4. There is no difference. Oly in readability

Answer (score 1):

They are equivalent. From [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)

```
| Keyword    | Sample                             | JPQL snippet             |
|------------|------------------------------------|--------------------------|
| Is, Equals | findByFirstname, findByFirstnameIs | … where x.firstname = ?1 |
|            | findByFirstnameEquals              |                          |
```